How do I exclude chat commands in C#?
I integrated chat GPT into my twitch chat and it responds to all messages.
I've excluded gpt to respond to some users (including myself) using the code below (top), but I want to exclude all messsages that start with "!" as well.
This is the very first time I've ever touched C# so I have no idea what to do.
I tried adding this (bottom) but it still responds to commands.
 List<string> excludeGptReply = new List<string>();
        excludeGptReply.Add(chatbotName);
        excludeGptReply.Add(broadcaster);
        excludeGptReply.Add("streamelements");
        excludeGptReply.Add("nightbot");
        excludeGptReply.Add("streamlabs");
        excludeGptReply.Add("pokemoncommunitygame");
        excludeGptReply.Add("kofistreambot");
        excludeGptReply.Add("fourthwallhq");
        excludeGptReply.Add("fossabot");


string message = args["message"].ToString();

        if (excludeGptReply.Contains(message.Trim().ToLower()))
        {
            return true; // Skip processing
        }

        if (message.StartsWith("!"))
        {
            return true; // Skip processing
        }


Considering you're filtering usernames based on if excludeGptReply.Contains(message.Trim().ToLower()), I'll assume that the message starts with the username. If so, checking if the message StartsWith("!") will check if the username starts with "!", which will never be the case.
I don't know the exact message format you have, but if it's something like username: message, you can select just the actual message text from that using IndexOf to find the first :  in the message (since that is the separator between username and message text)
string message = "username: message text"; // As an example incoming message
string separator = ": "; // What separates the username and text portions

int index = message.IndexOf(separator); // Find the index of the separator

string messageUsername = message[0..index]; // Username portion
string messageText = message[(index + separator.Length)..]; // Message text portion

if (excludeGptReply.Contains(messageUsername.ToLower())) {
    return true; // Skip processing
}

if (messageText.StartsWith("!")) {
    return true; // Skip processing
}


If the message format has the username and message as being separate... then it's as simple as
string messageUsername = args["username"]; // Username portion
string messageText = args["message"] // Message text portion

if (excludeGptReply.Contains(messageUsername.ToLower())) {
    return true; // Skip processing
}

if (messageText.StartsWith("!")) {
    return true; // Skip processing
}


I tried this, and, it probably works, but it didn't for me. I think because it is my first time with C# I'm not entirely sure where I am supposed to input the code.

What did you try that didn't work? Can you confirm the formatting of the message by doing something like Console.WriteLine(args["message"])?

I added the code you provided after the excludeGptReply.Add lines.
I believe it is username: message
